# Issues with ionic: Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'

Tags: gulp, ionic-framework

I've got some issues with trying to run gulp with Ionic.

The error message that pops up is this:

> Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'
>
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>       at require (module.js:380:17)
>       at Object. (/Users/emilymacleod/Desktop/myApp/gulpfile.js:2:13)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

I tried installing sass and gulp locally in the myApp folder as well as globally and no dice.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you add the required steps leading to the error message so someone can try to reproduce it?

Comment: I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-UwOWB9Io4&feature=youtu.be

And I'm at about 15:22 in. I'm trying to use the gulp sass command and it's not working.

Comment: my is now broken too. Tried a lot of uninstalls, installs etc. My error is module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:4:13)

Answer (score 6):

Kind of a long shot, but `gulp-util` is a [separated module](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util). You should install it locally:

```
npm install gulp gulp-util --save-dev
```

and require it in your code:

```js
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the problem of cannot find gulp-util even after doing the procedure at the end of this.  I can see it's added to the modules and the package.json, but that require statement seems to have an error. It doesn't seem to be working.

The PROCEDURE

`npm install gulp gulp-util --save-dev`
and require it in your code:
`var gutil = require('gulp-util');`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with gulp-sass. Error message was:
Uh oh! Looks like you're missing a module in your gulpfile:
Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'

Do you need to run `npm install`?

Resolved by executing the following:

- npm -g install npm
- npm install gulp-sass

Hope this help.